# Google Analytics and WordPress -- I can't find the right place to paste the code into

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I need to paste some Google Analytics code into my WordPress site. It's the latest WordPress theme, with some modifications.

I would like the Analytics code to track every page on the WordPress site.

Where do I paste the Analytics code?

I was told to do the following to find the place to paste the Analytics code:

--- In WordPress Admin, click 'Appearance'.
--- Click 'Editor'.
--- Click on "footer.php". Scroll to the very bottom of the text area. Find the < /body? line and right above it, add/paste your Analytics code.

But when I click 'Editor', I don't see "footer.php"....

This is what I see when I'm logged into WordPress Admin: https://skitch.com/richardclunan/fxsmg/dreamweaver

And this is the site that I want to add Google Analytics code to: [Richard Clunan -- Copywriter](http://richardclunan.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to just download the "Google Analytics for WordPress" plugin.
You can search for it from your dashboard "plugins" section and it updates all your new pages / post pages automatically. Otherwise you're stuck pasting code into each new page you make.

Comment: Thanks DFTR -- this sounds sensible. My Google Analytics account is tracking data from another website that is built in PHP, not WordPress -- as is my Adwords account -- I want to use both Analytics and Adwords on the WordPress website -- is it ok to use the plugin you mention considering I'm already using Analytics and Adwords on my php website?

Comment: Also, for the needs described, which is the appropriate plugin? When I search, the top 2 are: Google Analytics 3 codes for WordPress By Dechigno. And Google Analytics for WordPress By Joost de Valk.

Comment: I personally use the Joost de Valk and it works perfectly. You can only use the exact same key's if it is the same domain, otherwise you have to get new ones and add that domain to your google account. You'll have the list of domains show up on your dashboard, and can view reports for both from the same dashboard. (Thats my understanding... right now I only have one domain tracked.

Answer (score 1):

You are editing a child theme, it does not have all the files, only the files that are different from the parent. On the top right side switch to the parent theme called 'Twenty Eleven' in this case. Edit its footer.php

However, word of caution, if you update the theme through wordpress, the google analytics code would be gone. Possible work arounds for are:

1. Use a plugin as DFTR suggests
2. Copy the Twenty Eleven footer.php to Twenty Eleven child directory on your server and edit the child theme footer from wordpress.

Comment: Richard, it looks you've taken @DFTR's advice. You should reward the effort by accepting the answer (and, if you're particularly pleased, giving an upvote).

Answer (score -1):

To add Google Analytics to your WordPress site, you can go with these simple steps are as follows:

1. Enter your WordPress login information
2. Select Appearance
3. Theme Editor. After that
4. Click the Theme Header (header.php) file, which is located on the  right side under the Theme Files section.
5. Paste the tracking code you just copied from your Analytics profile before the closing  tag.
6. Then click Update File.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. However, the most important part of the question ("where is the right place") is not clear in your answer.